# jquery equivalent for JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

I'm using jquery as a library in my javascript code. But sometimes I have to `JSON.stringify()`.

When I want to keep my code IE compatible I use 
 
`$("head").append('<script type="text/javascript" src="../Includes/json2.js"></script>');` 
 to get my `JSON.stringify()` to work. Isn't there a equivalent in `jquery` for `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: IE8 and higher natively supports the `JSON.stringify` method. IE7 and lower is not something that you should use. And if for some reason you need to support such legacy crap all you need to do is include the json2.js script to your page (as seemingly you have already done).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There is no such functionality in jQuery. Use `JSON.stringify` or alternatively any jQuery plugin with similar functionality (e.g [jquery-json](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/)).

Comment: like https://raw.github.com/gist/754454/c6401b8cc461f84799503484a0c780a7622b164d/jQuery.stringify.js

Comment: @frumbert this gist is gone. Can you update the comment ?

Comment: Fixed link for above gist: https://gist.github.com/chicagoworks/754454