# Storing data Object coming from a response of jQuery ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am calling a web method from **asp.net 1.1** site and getting a response.

I use this object to populate some data, Now I want to store this object so that I can also save this data in database while saving click event.

How can I achieve this.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Ok").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Service.svc/xyz",
                    data: JSON.stringify(jData),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (**msg**) {
                        // STORE THIS msg object.
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: what is returning from /service.svc/xyz? if you want to save returning object in database, you can send another ajax request from success:function(data){ console.log(data); //do ajax request from here}

Comment: No..it is returning a object, which contains many information in json format..I have to go through the object later on and store what ever I want from that..

Comment: If it's json format object, you can easily go through that object. Example: data.item, data.name based on if your json object contains key: item, name. What exactly you want else?

Comment: Now I want to store this object to SOME HIDDEN field or so..so that while saving the form i can use that values.

Comment: I am writing that solution in my answer, check if it's ok

Comment: any progress on the solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448831/store-return-json-value-in-input-hidden-field..This helped much..anyways thanks for the ans.

Comment: Is there any difference between my solution and the link you provided? If you think my solution is ok, you can select it, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Ok").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Service.svc/xyz",
                data: JSON.stringify(jData),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                    // STORE THIS msg object.
                  //if hidden field has id 'name'
                  $('#name').val(data.name);//if json object contains a key 'name'
                  //if hidden field has class name
                  $('.name').val(data.name);
                  //if hidden field name is name <input type="text" name="name" />
                  $(document).filter(':[name=name]').val(data.name)
                  //do the same for all elements to save
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Ok").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Service.svc/xyz",
                    data: JSON.stringify(jData),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        // STORE THIS msg object.
                        /* now you can store data object to where you want to store.*/
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: This is a correct way to handle json object. Don't know why it's voted down

Comment: i don't know why. i have used this method many to handle JSON object even the kidz uses the same method.