# POST stringified object per hidden input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http, submit

I want to submit some data which I attach to an input element. The server get's this element, with correct ID, but it has no value.

```
<form id="sub_form" method="post" action="acc_manage.lp"> 
    <input type="text" name="container" id="sub_inp" value=""> </input>
</form>
```

`sub_inp` receives its input from a specific event, which calls:

```
function execute_submit(){
    $("#sub_inp").val(JSON.stringify(foo));
    // .val() returns a stringified object 
    console.log( $("#sub_inp").val() )
    if ($("#sub_inp").val() != "") {
        $("#sub_form").submit();
  };
```

Value of the post request on server-side is this:

> post={ container={} }, formdata={}, errtag={} }

Why is this and how can I fix it? I am using jQuery 2.1.3

Comment: an JS object, let's say { a:"b", c:"d" }

Comment: alert(foo)  prints [object][object], however alert( JSON.stringify(foo)) prints what I've expectet, "{ a:'b', c:'d' } " in this example.

Comment: Where is the server-side code that is receiving the response? Also note that `input` elements do not require a `</input>` tag.

Comment: I havent written the serverside myself, but it's based on this: http://www.teratronik.org/core4/Core4Event/httpd/cgi.html

Comment: But what is the actual code you've used? We can't diagnose the problem without seeing what the cause is.

Comment: The entire page is assambled in lua and given per .cgi . In this script, there's the line  >  if ( cgi.post ) then print( table.tostring( cgi )) end <  this is where I've got the post value from.

Comment: Sadly, I can't provide the entire script. Do you have a specific assumption? Would the entire post message help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might some issues/misunderstandings about how your form is getting submitted, and what happens there. I cannot tell for sure, because some of the important code is missing form your example...

If your form has an `action` attribute:

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
   ...
</form>
```

> On submit, send the form-data to a file named "demo_form.asp" (to
>   process the input)

([w3schools: form_action](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp))

If you want to run javascript code on submit use `onsubmit` attribute

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
   ...
</form>
```

> Execute a JavaScript when a form is submitted

([w3schools: onsubmit](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp))

If you specify both you might get unexpected results on the server side.

Similar problem: [HTML form action and onsubmit issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262797/html-form-action-and-onsubmit-issues)

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, after clarifying that your code javascript code is running, we have to assume that the row:

```
$("#sub_inp").val(JSON.stringify(foo));
```

is messing up the HTML value of the input, like mentioned in this answer: [store return json value in input hidden field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448831/store-return-json-value-in-input-hidden-field#18443279)

Comment: Informative. I've given sub_inp the default value "test" to check if there's some problem as you mentioned it. But the problem stays the same. The received value isn't {"test"} but simply {}. So the value get's altered before submition.

Comment: I see. Take a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448831/store-return-json-value-in-input-hidden-field#18443279

Comment: Can it be that `JSON.stringify(foo)` is messing the HTML value data up.

Comment: Thats it. Could you please add this to your answer, so others can see the solution quicker?

Comment: *If you specify both, your javascript won't run before submit* — False. The submit event handler is fired before the form is submitted.

Comment: You're right, I tried. I took the phrase away. Thanks!

Comment: DDan, simply .replace(/"/g, "|") (| or any other digit that cannot occur in the object) should be an easier solution, depending on what the serverside wants to do with the data. In my case, the JSON object will be parsed to a lua table, therefore .replace is much easier.