# When using AjaxHelper to retrieve a partial view, the embedded data is always the same

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, ajaxhelper

We use ASP.NET MVC 5's `AjaxHelper` and `Ajax.BeginForm` to request a partial view. That request also needs some JSON data in order to update a map control.

The view rendering part of the process works great (a table body is replaced with the strongly-typed partial view), but the JSON data (embedded into the `data-json` attribute of the `div` element as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18443279/284743) and retrieved in my `OnSuccess` function) *always has the same value*.

To eliminate the controller code or ViewBag as culprit, I replaced the JSON data (originally retrieved from the ViewBag) with a direct call to `DateTime.Now`. Sure enough, the same DateTime is printed each time in `updateMap()` (e.g., `2/11/2016+5:24:42+PM`)

I've tried disabling caching, and changing the HTML method to Post, in my `AjaxOptions`.

In the Parent View (changing the ListBox selection submits the form):

```
@model string

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Project List";
    AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "tableBody",
        OnSuccess = "updateMap",
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        AllowCache = false
    };
}


    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetProjectsData", ajaxOpts))
    {
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Project State</legend>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.ListBox("selectedStates", ViewBag.StatesList as MultiSelectList,
                       new { @class = "chzn-select", data_placeholder = "Choose  States...", style = "width:350px;", onchange = "$(this.form).submit();" })
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Project Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Project Firm
            </th>
            <th>
                Project Location
            </th>
            <th>
                Building Type
            </th>
            <th>
                Project Budget
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody">
        @Html.Action("GetProjectsData", new { selectedStates = Model })
    </tbody>

</table>

    <script>
        function updateMap() {
            var jsonData = $("#geoJsonData").attr("data-json");
            var decoded = decodeURIComponent(jsonData);
            console.log(decoded); // always prints same value
        }
    </script>
```

The partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<OurModel>

<div id="geoJsonData" data-json="@Url.Encode(DateTime.Now.ToString())"></div>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAME)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.COMPANY_NAME)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.STATE)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BUILDING_TYPE)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BUDGET_AMT)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I'm hesitant to jettison the MVC helper classes' pattern of returning a partial view and instead [manually render a view into a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18667715/284743). Why is the updated tablebody visible on screen, but when jQuery requests the div element it always has the same data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting...replacing the div with a good old hidden input element worked. Now fresh data is retrieved each time.

This

```
<div id="geoJsonData" data-json="@Url.Encode(DateTime.Now.ToString())"></div>
```

Became this

```
<input id="geoJsonData" type="hidden" value="@Url.Encode(DateTime.Now.ToString())" />
```

I wonder why the `data-json` in the `div` remained "stale" while the `value` of the `input` field did the trick?