# How to insert multiple values in one checkbox in jsp

Tags: html, mysql, database, eclipse, jsp

I want to insert the row of data that I checked into the database.(Arm Exercises, Count and Degree) However, the database only inserts the arm value. I understand that it is inserting only arm value because of my `value="<%=arm%>"`. How should I change so that I can insert the row of data at once ?

[image: HTML]

**JSP Code**

```
<% 

        String userId       = request.getParameter("UserID");
        String[] arm            = request.getParameterValues("Arm");
        String armNumber    = request.getParameter("ArmNumber");
        String degree       = request.getParameter("Degree");
        String remark       = request.getParameter("Remark");
        String Timestamp    = request.getParameter("Time");
        //String leg            = request.getParameter("Leg");
        //String legNumber  = request.getParameter("LegNumber");

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
        out.println(userId);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
        out.println(arm);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
        out.println(armNumber);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
        out.println(degree);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
        out.println(remark);
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
        out.println(Timestamp);
        out.println("</td>");

        //out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
        //out.println(leg);
        //out.println("</td>");
        //out.println("<td style='width: 10%'>");
        //out.println(legNumber);
        //out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

        int count           =0;
        Connection conn     = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String connURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/HIHI?user=123&password=123";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);


            for(int i=0;i<arm.length;i++){
                    String sql="Insert into assign(UserID, Arm, ArmNumber, Degree, Remark, Time) Values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    PreparedStatement pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                    pstmt.setString (1,userId);
                    pstmt.setString (2,arm[i]);
                    pstmt.setString (3,armNumber);
                    pstmt.setString (4,degree);
                    pstmt.setString (5,remark);

                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    Date date = new Date();                                     
                    pstmt.setTimestamp(6,new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime()));

                    //pstmt.setString   (4,leg);
                    //pstmt.setString   (5,legNumber);

                int rec=pstmt.executeUpdate();

                if (rec==1)
                    count++;

            }


%>


        <form action="assign.jsp" method="post">
            <label><%=count%> assigned!!</label>
            <td style width="50%">
            <p><input type="submit" value="Return" name="ReturnBtn" /></p>
        </form>


<%
        conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{

        }
%>
```

**HTML,JSP Code**

```
<td style="width: 5%"><input class="mychkbox" type="checkbox"
                value="<%=arm%>" form="multipleAssign" name="Arm" /></td>
```

Comment: see [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/5813861), code java in JSP is very bad practice.

Comment: store it as json value

Comment: How do i do that? @sumesh TG

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448831/store-return-json-value-in-input-hidden-field

Comment: thanks for your help @sumesh TG